# What are the compatible Hortonworks Data Platform(HDP) versions for installing HAWQ Plugin

Tags: hadoop, centos, hortonworks-data-platform, cloud-foundry, hawq

I was trying to install the hawq plugin on ambari on top of hdp 2.3 and it fails. The command I am using to check the status is

```
curl -u admin:admin -H X-Requested-By:devops -i -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/Sandbox/services/HAWQ?fields=ServiceInfo/state"
```

And the procedure for creating hawq on hdp is here [link] ( http://blog.pivotal.io/big-data-pivotal/p-o-v/pivotal-hawq-lands-in-the-hortonworks-sandbox).  I would be grateful if someone can say what could be the reason for failure

[image]

Comment: Image corresponding to this error can be seen at http://i.stack.imgur.com/9MlSn.png

Comment: You can poke around `/var/log` on the sandbox to find the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of HDP with HAWQ 1.3.  You need to use HDP 2.2, not 2.3.  Support for HDP 2.3 is coming but not available yet.

Comment: Hello @jon . Thanks for your response. I have come to know that I need to use HDP 2.2.6 and above but I am not aware that HDP 2.3 woudn't work. It is hard to get older versions of HDP for download from web :( . I have HDP 2.2.4 which is again incompatible for working with HAWQ.

Comment: http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/220/hdb/releasenotes/HAWQ220ReleaseNotes.html#topic_g53_tgv_2v  You should use HAWQ 2.x, not 1.3.  See the support matrix to determine which version of Hortonworks and HAWQ you should use.  HAWQ 2.0 works with HDP 2.3 but ideally, you should use the latest version of HAWQ.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find older versions here:

**Sandbox:**
http://hortonworks.com/products/releases/hdp-2-2/#install
HDP 2.2.4.2 will also work (which is what's in the sandbox I beleive).

**If you're installing your own cluster:**
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.1.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_hdp_stack_repositories.html

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Could you up vote my question if it makes sense to you.